# JSF 2.0 Validation errors result the input fields to display local values instead of updated model values

Tags: jsf-2, validation

The application uses JSF 2.0 framework.
User inputs values to a form. When user selects save, some fields have validation errors and some don't.
User clicks on cancel button. Then user clicks the update button again.
Even though the modal values are updated, the fields which had valid values when save was selected display the local values instead of the updated model values.

I solved this issue by adding a resetValues() method in the action method of cancel.
The resetValues() loops through the list of children and reset the local values to null.

Is there a better solution for this problem to improve the performance of the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cancel button should recreate the view. You can do it by returning a navigation outcome to the same view, if necessary with `faces-redirect=true`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. And your solution works too. It is working only if the method returns page name instead of empty string.

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed, it has to be a valid view ID instead of empty string or `null` or `void`. You could in theory also even do `<h:commandButton value="cancel" action="#{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId}" immediate="true" />`.

Comment: The form has two panel groups, open and closed state. The cancel button has ajax. If I remove ajax for the command button it works. But if I add ajax for the command button with immediate = true and execute="@this", the previous values are  retained.

Comment: Ajax will only navigate if you use `faces-redirect=true`.

Comment: I am returning "viewId?faces-redirect=true" and still the values are displaying the local values instead of the updated model values.    `<h:commandLink id="cancel" value="Cancel"immediate="true"> <br/>     <f:ajax event="click" render="@form" execute="@this" listener="#{bean.cancel"/> <br/>
    </h:commandLink>`

Comment: You have to do the navigation job in `action` method, not in `listener` method. `<h:commandLink id="cancel" value="Cancel" action="#{bean.cancel}" immediate="true"><f:ajax /></h:commandLink>`

Comment: It is finally working. I changed the method to action method instead of listener. Thanks for the information.